# Python: A problem with the package import from ... import * using __all__ and __init__

Tags: python, import, package

I have the following Python package with 2 moludes:

```
-pack1 
|-__init__ 
|-mod1.py 
|-mod2.py
-import_test.py
```

with the code:

```
# in mod1.py
a = 1
```

and

```
# in mod2.py
from mod1 import a
b = 2
```

and the `__init__` code:

```
# in __init__.py
__all__ = ['mod1', 'mod2']
```

Next, I am trying to import the package:

```
# in import_test.py
from pack1 import *
```

But I get an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'

If I remove the dependency "from mod1 import a" in mod2.py, the import goes correctly. But that dependency makes the import incorrect with that exception "ModuleNotFoundError".

???

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that from `mod2` perspective the first level in which it will search for a module is in the path from which you are importing it (here I am assuming that pack1 is not in your PYTHONPATH and that you are importing it from the same directory where `pack1` is contained).

This means that if `pack1` is in the directory `/dir/to/pack1` and you do:

```py
from mod1 import a
```

Python will look for `mod1` in the same directory as `pack1`, i.e., `/dir/to/pack1`.

**To solve your issue it is enough to do either:**

```py
from pack1.mod1 import a
```

or in Python 3.5+

```py
from .mod1 import a
```

> As a side note, unless this is a must for you, I do not recommend designing your package to be used as `from pack import *`, even if `__all__` exists to give you better control of your public API.

Comment: This solution "from pack1.mod1 import a" works. I think I have understand what was wrong. Thanks!